# How to initialize default values for GeoPoint in a data class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to convert documents to objects from Firestore, but when I create my data class , I dont know how to initialize the GeoPoint with default values as it needs to be declared for an empty constructor

```
data class MapObj(val geopoint:Geopoint) //--> how to initialize it to get an empty constructor
```

The problem relies on this line

```
val obj = snapshot.toObject(MapObj::class.java)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Firestore SDK isn't finding a default, no argument constructor for MapObj.  Kotlin data classes don't have one if all of their properties are declared with `val`.  For properties declared `val`, Kotlin requires that their values be specified in the constructor, since they can't possibly change afterward.

If you must get a data class back from Firestore, you will have to make all of its properties optional `var` with a default value, so that Kotlin will generate a no-arg constructor for it.

```
data class MapObj(var geopoint: Geopoint? = null)
```